# Using BizTalk WCF-WSHttp send adapter to consume web service with WS-Security over HTTP

Tags: biztalk, ws-security, biztalk-2009

A third party supplier has exposed a web service which we need to consume.

It is a SOAP web service which also expects [WS-Addressing](http://www.w3.org/Submission/ws-addressing/) and [WS-Security](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=wss) elements in the header.

I believe it should be possible to consume this web service using the [WCF-WSHttp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226477%28v=bts.10%29.aspx) adapter in BizTalk 2009.  However I am new to both WCF and WS-Security so am struggling a little.

I attempted to set up the send adapter with the following settings:

- Security mode: **Transport**
- Transport client credential type: **Certificate**
- Client certificate thumbprint: [selected]

The first problem I have encountered is that when using this security configuration, BizTalk is forcing me to specify an HTTPS endpoint, yet the third party web service is over HTTP.

This is the error BizTalk gives me if I try to specify an HTTP endpoint:

[image]

Is this a limitation of BizTalk, or a fundamental issue with the way the supplier has exposed their web service?

Additionally, if anyone can point me towards any useful guidance on using the WCF adapters with WS-Security it would be really useful as I have struggled to find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get BizTalk to accept the binding, configure it with the https://... address and then change the address in binding file and re-import the binding.

If BizTalk allows this (ie this is only a constraint of the WCF dialogue) then you will be in a position to actually consume the service and test it.

Comment: Cunning idea ... trying this now

Comment: It allowed me to import the modified bindings, but on testing the message was suspended with the same error message: `System.ArgumentException: The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'.`  So BizTalk will not allow this.  However is it a valid scenario?  Maybe I should modify my question.

Comment: I don't know for certain to be honest, but it seems to me logical that you can't use a secure certificate across non-secure http. Maybe you should contact the service publisher and ask them.

Comment: I've accepted your answer as you helped me establish that BizTalk will simply not allow this.

Answer (score 1):

Security mode: Transport required https. It is the concept of WCf and wont work with any other tweak

Answer (score 0):

If you hit this problem, ensure "Security mode" drop-down from the "Security" tab is set correctly.

[image]

Comment: This solved my problem in BizTalk 2013 with a WCF-BasicHttp send port! Security mode "None" requires an http scheme, while "Transport" requires https.

Comment: Great, please click the up arrow!

Comment: I did! It's unfair that the correct answer (for me at least) had -1.